# ElasticSearch 2.3 _search for more than 10,000 paged items

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, search, limit

In ElasticSearch 2.3 (and in the latest releases) there is a [index.max_result_window](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) setting which restricts the [search query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-body.html) to a `from` + `size` value that is less than 10,000 entries. e.g.

```
from: 0 size: 10,000 is ok
from: 0 size: 10,001 is not ok
from: 9,000 size: 1,001 is not ok
```

In the latest release, 7.10, the documentation says this can be worked around by using [search-after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after). However, due to legacy data, I need something similar in ES 2.3. I'm curious if there are any good options?

Why do I need this? In our data we've a child / parent hierarchy. One query we run against this data is to determine all the unique parents over a certain date range. Currently we retrieve this information using an `aggregate` query. i.e.

```
{
  "query": { "match_all_in_date_range": {} },
  "aggs": {
    "parents": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parentId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which, interestingly, returns all the parents even if there are more than 10,000. i.e. It does not appear to be affected by the `index.max_result_window` limit.

But this aggregation is expensive and time consuming. As a result I'm evaluating if it's possible to remove it and "aggregate" the data in our own code. i.e. Retrieve all the objects, read their `parentId` field, and record the unique ids.

But it *looks* like the `index.max_result_window` limit may break that idea. i.e. Unless I'm mistaken. Two ideas I had to work around this would be

- Rather than paging I should modify the query to exclude the `parentIds` I've already retrieved (the downside being that it could take longer to run and will cause the query to grow until the end)
- To move over to the more heavy duty [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-scroll.html) (which may be more suitable for other usages)

But I'd be curious to hear if there are other options available to me?

Comment: why not increase `index.max_result_window` to a number larger than the docs in your index?

Comment: @Nate I'm wary of the warning in the documentation re: "heap memory". It could introduce memory management problems. This is compounded by the fact that I'm not certain there's an upper limit I can set. There could be millions of objects stored. Randomly choosing 10 million as the `index.max_result_window` might give a higher ceiling but in some cases I may still hit my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide the search into smaller ones, separating by hour for example, or by other field, so that each search returns less than 10,000 results

Comment: This is the approach we ended up adopting.